# asp.net RangeValidator, accept MinimumValue and MaximumValue with comma instead of dot

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a TextBox I am validating numbers between 0 and 1. I want the system to accept the value 0,5 instead of 0.5

```
CultureInfo before = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    try

    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        var rngVald = new RangeValidator
            {
            ControlToValidate = IdOfMyTextBox,
            MinimumValue = "0",
            MaximumValue = "1"
            Type = ValidationDataType.Double,
            ErrorMessage = "<span class=\"error\">*value should be bet. 0 and 1</span>"
            };
        panel.Controls.Add(rngVald);
    }

finally
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = before;
    }
```

Even though in Germany the floating points numbers are with comma but still the system is not accepting 0,5 as valid number.

Comment: Where you have changed the culture? You have to do that in `Page_Init` at the latest

Comment: I am doing it in Page_Load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have changed the culture? You have to do that in `Page_Init` at the latest.

Also, changing the culture back to what is was before after you have added the dynamic validator to the panel doesn't work. This is not the time when it validates the input. So it will take the culture that is active when validation takes place, not when you add it to the page.

Comment: Now I have put the code in `Page_Init` but the result is still the same.

Comment: @Kamran: sure, because you change the culture back in the finally. That doesnt work as i've explained in m answer